# Google Maps API Send Email With Directions

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I used the Google Maps API to create a map with a custom input field that displays directions to a fixed address after the user submits the starting point in the form.  Now I would like the user to be able to email herself or another person a link to google maps with the directions already plugged in.  This functionality already exists on regular google maps but I don't believe there's anything built into the API for reproducing this.  Does anyone have any ideas or thoughts?

PS, sorry I can't include a link to the site because it has not launched yet and I don't think my client would want everyone looking at their new site before it's finished :).  However, I'll try to clarify as much as needed if anyone is confused.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Seth is right, you can generate the right url to Google Map service knowing the correct parameters. 
[This ressource](http://gearside.com/easily-link-to-locations-and-directions-using-the-new-google-maps/) lists several url formats.

My personal favorite is :

```
https://www.google.com/maps/dir/<start-location>/<other-location>
```

You can use it with an address or latitude/longitude, like :

```
 https://www.google.com/maps/dir/48.856614,2.352222/52.520007,13.404954
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just create a link that is populated by your code.

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?&q=1000+Some+Street,+City,+NC+to+1000+Some+Other+Street,+City,+CA
```

That will open to Google maps and will automatically get directions.